# Change order of a string using an array indexes/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am stuck with this challenge, any help would be great.

'Create a function that takes both a string and an array of numbers as arguments. Rearrange the letters in the string to be in the order specified by the index numbers. Return the "remixed" string.
Examples

remix("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]) ➞ "acdb"'

My attempt -

```
function remix(str, arr) {
var arr2 = [];
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    arr2.splice(arr[i], 0, str[i]);
}
return arr2.join("");
```

}

This will solve some but not all of the tests.
EG.
("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2]) = "acdb" but some do not.
EG.
"responsibility", [0, 6, 8, 11, 10, 7, 13, 5, 3, 2, 4, 12, 1, 9])
should be - "rtibliensyopis" mine is "rteislbpoyinsi"

Comment: I did not quite get the question `[0, 3, 1, 2]` how does it remix it to  `"acdb"`? Could you please give me a clue.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi I think I get it, `0,3,2,1` means "move `"a"` to `0`, then `"b"` to `3`, `"c"` to `1` and `"d"` to `2`. This gives the expected `"acdb"`` (so the array tells where to move letters, not which letters to take).

Comment: Perfect! now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the value of `arr[i]` as target index for the actual letter.

```js
function remix(str, arr) {
    var result = [],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        result[arr[i]] = str[i];
    }

    return result.join('');
}

console.log(remix("abcd", [0, 3, 1, 2])); // "acdb"
console.log(remix("responsibility", [0, 6, 8, 11, 10, 7, 13, 5, 3, 2, 4, 12, 1, 9])) // "rtibliensyopis"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(text, nums){
var arr = [];
for(var num in nums){
    arr.push(text.charAt(nums[num]));       
}
return arr;
```

};

I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer - misinterpreted the question at first.

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to fill the positions in a new array with letters from `str` based on target positions from `arr`:

```
const remix = ( str, arr ) => (
    arr.reduce( (acc, target, idx) => { 
      acc[target] = str[idx]; return acc; 
    }, [])
  ).join('');
```

or reduce the array of letters in `str` into an array:

```
const remix = ( str, arr ) => (
    [...str].reduce( (acc, letter, idx) => { 
      acc[arr[idx]] = letter; return acc; 
    }, [])
  ).join('');
```

Comment: I don't think this will return the outputs that OP mentioned. Check out Nina Scholz's answer. I myself did not quite get what remix exactly is.